# Multiple Column returns undefined in MVC using MCAutocomplete Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

my multiple column in mvc returns undefined.

what do i missed? or there is wrong with my code? pls help.

[image]

Controller

```
public ActionResult EmployeeIDSearch(string term)
    {
        // Get Tags from database
        using (var ctx = new DASH_FAEntities())
        {
            var tags = (from e in ctx.EmployeeMasters
                        where e.EMT_EmployeeID.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower().Trim())
                        select new
                        {
                            EmployeeID = e.EMT_EmployeeID.Trim(),
                            FullName = e.EMT_FirstName.Trim() + " " + e.EMT_LastName.Trim(),
                            Department = e.EMT_Department.Trim()
                        }).ToArray();

            return Json(tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBox("EmployeeID", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Employee ID", @id="employeeid" })
```

Jquery

```
function customRenderItem(ul, item) {
            var t = '<span class="mcacCol1">' + item[0] + '</span><span class="mcacCol2">' + item[1] + '</span><span class="mcacCol3">' + item[2] + '</span>',
                result = $('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"></li>')
                .data('item.autocomplete', item)
                .append('<a class="ui-corner-all" style="position:relative;" tabindex="-1">' + t + '</a>')
                .appendTo(ul);

            return result;
        }

        var columns = [{ name: 'Employee ID', minWidth: '100px' }, { name: 'Full Name', minWidth: '100px' }, { name: 'Department', minWidth: '100px' }]

        $("#employeeid").mcautocomplete({
            showHeader: true, 
            columns: columns,
            source: '@Url.Action("EmployeeIDSearch", "Home")',
            select: function (event, ui) {
                this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] : '');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

[mcautocomplete.js](https://github.com/alforno-productions/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete)

I already checked the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/d3t7V/) file of this plugin. I only just change the source and added another column. But still undefined when I look for the employee id.

I break point my controller where I get my source and it has a value every time I time for employee id.

Also I've already googled and i found nothing. It's been yesterday and I don't know what to do. I don't want to use other plugin because my web would be slow for using different plugin.

Please Help.

Comment: You have spaces in the `name` property so they do not match the property names. Looking at the docs, it looks like you then need to specify the `valueField` property - e.g . `var columns = [{ name: 'Employee ID', minWidth: '100px', valueField: EmployeeID }, .....` etc

Comment: but how would I change the column name? I mean not as its property name but its view name?

Also by what you say, My department column has exact name with my object but it still undefined

Comment: Try adding the `valueField` as per my last comment

Comment: Ok @StephenMuecke I'll try it

Comment: Your source should be the actual JSON array, not just the path the action. Change your code to AJAX fetch the results from the action then use that as the source

Comment: @BrentMannering how?

Comment: @StephenMuecke well it works now. I just add valueField as you state above.

But I have encountered a new problem. When I select an item to the dropdown, it show undefined in the textbox. Can you help about it?

Comment: @qwerzxcxyz, Thats a separate issue and you will need to ask a new question with the relevant code (there is nothing in this one about a dropdownlist), and I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not literally mean a dropdown list, i mean is when I select now on autocomplete(which look like a dropdownlist for me), it returns undefined on the textbox

Comment: OK (I assumed you were referring to a `<select>`somewhere). Are you saying all the items display correctly, but when you click on an item (and the dropdown closes), the text in your textbox is "undefined"?

Comment: OK, got it. You need to change `this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] : '');` to `this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item.EmployeeID : '');` (refer [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqk0xu1r/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/alforno-productions/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete), the syntax your using for the `columns` property is only suuitable if the `source` is an array of arrays. For example it would work it the data was

```
[['1', 'Joe Blogs', 'Administration'], ['2', 'John Doe', 'Finance']]
```

but your controller method is returning an array of objects, so you need to also specify the `valueField` property. Change the `columns` definition to

```
var columns = [{ name: 'Employee ID', minWidth: '100px', valueField: 'EmployeeID' },
    { name: 'Full Name', minWidth: '100px', valueField: 'FullName' }, 
    { name: 'Department', minWidth: '100px', valueField: 'Department' }]
```

where the value of `valueField` match the property name.

**Edit**

Since you now adding objects, not arrays, you also need to change

```
this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] : '');
```

to

```
this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item.EmployeeID : '');
```

in order to display the selected value in the textbox (refer [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqk0xu1r/) for a working example).